# How do I add columns to devise after the initial create_table rake?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, devise

I installed Devise, raked, and then realized afterwards, that I want to add :confirmable.

Can I go back to the same initial migration and just uncomment out the helper that I want and then rake db:migrate again?

I tried it and it didn't seem to work.  But I haven't seen an example of how to create a follow-on migration.

Thanks!

This is what I tried:

```
  1 class AddConfirmableToUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration 
  2   def self.up 
  3     change_table :users do |t| 
  4       t.confirmable 
  5     end 
  6     add_index :users, :confirmation_token,   :unique => true  
  7   end 
  8    
  9   def self.down 
 10     remove_column :users, :confirmation_token 
 11   end 
 12   
 13 end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add the proper columns yourself like so:

```
class AddConfirmableToUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    change_table :users do |t|
      t.string :confirmation_token
      t.datetime :confirmed_at
      t.datetime :confirmation_sent_at
    end

    add_index :users, :confirmation_token, :unique => true
  end

  def self.down
    change_table :users do |t|
      t.remove :confirmation_token, :confirmed_at, :confirmation_sent_at
    end

    remove_index :users, :confirmation_token
  end
end
```

Comment: okay I wasn't sure exactly how to do this, but this is what I was looking for I think...I used the helpers as above, should that do it as well?

Comment: I would think using the helpers would work but I've never actually tried it.

Answer (score 0):

Your migration should work. Did you check your `User` model to make sure `:confirmable` is enabled? It's commented out by default.

If you don't mind losing your data you can just do

```
> rake db:drop
```

Otherwise you can just edit the initial migration and do a rollback.

```
# get the current migration version
> rake db:version
> Current version: ****************41
> rake db:rollback ****************40
```

Make your changes

```
> rake db:migrate
```