# undefined method skip_confirmation! - devise, omniauth

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, omniauth

Trying to set up facebook authentication using devise, omniauth (including facebook-omniauth) on an app hosted on heroku. 
Call to facebook API works, but I do not manage to skip the confirmation step after callback.

I followed the github tutorial on omniauth : https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/OmniAuth:-Overview

and also read and tried to implement this :
[Devise skip_confirmation! not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8672189/devise-skip-confirmation-not-working)

But I keep getting the following error in my heroku log :

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `skip_confirmation!')
```

Here is how my devise.rb looks :

```
config.omniauth :facebook, "API_KEY", "API_SECRET"    

{:strategy_class => OmniAuth::Strategies::Facebook,
:scope => 'email, offline_access', :client_options => {:ssl => {:ca_file => '/usr/lib/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt'}}}
```

Here is my omniauth_callbacks_controller.rb :

```
class Users::OmniauthCallbacksController < Devise::OmniauthCallbacksController
  def facebook
   # You need to implement the method below in your model (e.g. app/models/user.rb)
   @user = User.find_for_facebook_oauth(request.env["omniauth.auth"], current_user)

   if @user.persisted?
     sign_in_and_redirect @user, :event => :authentication #this will throw if @user is not activated
    set_flash_message(:notice, :success, :kind => "Facebook") if is_navigational_format?
   else
    session["devise.facebook_data"] = request.env["omniauth.auth"]
    redirect_to new_user_registration_url
   end
  end
end
```

Here is my user.rb model :

```
def self.find_for_facebook_oauth(auth, signed_in_resource=nil)
 user = User.where(:provider => auth.provider, :uid => auth.uid).first
 unless user
       user = User.new(name:auth.extra.raw_info.name,
                    provider:auth.provider,
                    uid:auth.uid,
                    email:auth.info.email,
                    password:Devise.friendly_token[0,20],
                    )
       user.skip_confirmation!
       user.save
  end
  user
end
```

Thanks for your help !

Comment: Do you have the confirmable module on the user?

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  devise :confirmable
end

Comment: I have this : 
__devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
:recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable, :omniauthable__

Answer (score 18, accepted):

So if I'm right (not 100% secure), you need to declare that your model has the module confirmable, add the confirmable module:

```
   devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable, :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable, :omniauthable, :confirmable
```

And make sure that you have the fields for the confirmable module on your users table, you should have the fields confirmation_token and confirmed_at

If you don't have those fields, check on this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6338574/how-do-i-add-columns-to-devise-after-the-initial-create-table-rake) how to add them.

Comment: Yes thanks a lot, I missed this one !
I added __confirmable__ user.rb , ran __rails g migration add_confirmable_to_devise__ and rake db:migrate


Now I get NoMethodError (undefined method `is_navigational_format?') on OmniauthCallbacksController. I have to find out why !

Comment: that's probably part of your code, if_navigational_format? is not part of devise.

Comment: In that part of the code, where you have the set_flash_message, I usually use something like this:

        flash[:notice] = I18n.t "devise.omniauth_callbacks.success", :kind => "Linkedin";
        sign_in(@user);
        redirect_to after_sign_in_path_for(@user)

Comment: Thanks a lot, your first answer solved my problem, I will now work on the second issue which is not related !